# database design for checkout and order table

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design

I am designing a database for e-commerce. I am confused regarding the checkout and order table. I am not sure if I need to create separate `order` table when most of the things is already done on `checkout` table.

Here is the design as of now

```
class Product(ModelWithMetadata, PublishableModel):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name="products",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="variants")
    variant_attributes = models.ManyToManyField(VariantAttribute, related_name="productvariants")


class Checkout(ModelWithMetadata):
    """A shopping checkout."""
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_change = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="checkouts",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    email = models.EmailField()
    token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, related_name="+", editable=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, related_name="+", editable=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    shipping_method = models.ForeignKey(
        ShippingMethod,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="checkouts",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")

    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE_LENGTH,
        default=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
    )
    country = CountryField(default=get_default_country)

    discount_amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=settings.DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS,
        decimal_places=settings.DEFAULT_DECIMAL_PLACES,
        default=0,
    )
    discount = MoneyField(amount_field="discount_amount", currency_field="currency")
    discount_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    voucher_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    # gift_cards = models.ManyToManyField(GiftCard, blank=True, related_name="checkouts")

    objects = CheckoutQueryset.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-last_change", "pk")


class CheckoutLine(models.Model):
    """A single checkout line.
    """

    checkout = models.ForeignKey(
        Checkout, related_name="lines", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    variant = models.ForeignKey(
        "product.ProductVariant", related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

The additional things that is not covered in checkout table is about order tracking and refund. It is because I am confused if it's better to use that also on `checkout` table or create new `order` table and deal refund and tracking policy accordingly.

If it is better to use separate `order` table then can anyone enlighten me the benefits and how it is possible, please?

Comment: Is this purely technical or also practical question?

Comment: My intention is to understand the table design(practical) with explanation if order table is needed. Sorry I am not good in English so my question might confused you.

Answer (score 2):

You must not only create a separate Order model, but also a separate Product model and integrate secondary costs differently. The reason is this: Orders **must be** static information for legal/financial reasons. They record something that happened in the past. It must match the price of the product at that time, the shipping costs, payment fees etc. All this information cannot be changed and in the checkout they are linked to entities that are mutable or even deletable.

For a product you usually do something like this:

```py
class PurchasedItem(models.Model):
     original_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     ...  # minimal set of product attributes that allow delivery of the order
          # with the correct item (color / size / etc) and fixed price
          # Basically flatten product variant and product attributes that are
          # relevant.
```

This way, you can still make repeat orders happening as long as the product is still available. There's a lot to consider, but basically every time you want to make a ForeignKey on an order item, you must think if changing the linked item changes the order.

So your OrderLine becomes something like this:

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, ...)
    item = models.ForeignKey(PurchasedItem, ...)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
```

The Order model:

- If you allow deletion of user accounts, then Order.user must be nullable.
- Shipping and billing address should be OneToOneField and a new copy must be made each time an order is made -or (better)- flatten the address attributes into the order.
- Shipping method: flatten and record final price
- Currency: record exchange rate, make it possible to change exchange rate once bank statement comes in
- Country: record the country name, if you want to keep a link to country for statistical purposes, make it nullable. Just in my lifetime, USSR, East/West Germany, Yugoslavia to name a few, ceased existing.

Hopefully this helps you get started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now, I am clear why I need separate model. Checkout model is temporary.